# How to sort prime-ui datatable, based on more than one column

Tags: jquery-ui, prime-ui

I want to sort the datatable based on 2 columns. If I use the following property,

{sortField: 'ColumnHeader'}

Its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work with the current primeui (at the time of this answer it is `1.1`). Have a look at the sort function:

```
    sort: function(field, order) {
        if(this.options.selectionMode) {
            this.selection = [];
        }

        if(this.options.lazy) {
            this.options.datasource.call(this, this._onLazyLoad, this._createStateMeta());
        }
        else {
            this.data.sort(function(data1, data2) {
                var value1 = data1[field],
                value2 = data2[field],
                result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

                return (order * result);
            });

            if(this.options.selectionMode) {
                this.selection = [];
            }

            if(this.paginator) {
                this.paginator.puipaginator('option', 'page', 0);
            }

            this._renderData();
        }
    },
```

As you can see it uses the [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort%20Array.prototype.sort()) function and accesses the field-to

```
var value1 = data1[field],
value2 = data2[field],
```

Maybe you can override this particular function and use your own `sort` method instead.

Comment: since prime-ui uses jquery-ui, is there any way, we can use the sort functionality of the jquery datatable ? If yes, please give an example

Comment: What is 'the jquery datatable'? I did not find any datatable at https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Try to override the prime-ui's sort function. Then you can order like you want to.

Comment: MultiSort support will be available in 2.1. release due August 2015.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#datatableSort

Its available in Prime UI version 4.1.3

Comment: Try to avoid posting link only answers.